# display content in TD based on space available

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have a table as below

```
<c:set var="var1" value="this is text one"/>
<c:set var="var2" value="this is text two"/>
<table>
<tr>
<td width="100%">
<span>${var1} | ${var2} </span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

question:
I need to calculate the available space in the TD and display content based on that. Meaning, 
1. if there is enough space to display var1 and var2, then display the same.
2. If there is not enough space to display var2, then truncate var2 with ellipses. (this is taken care of..)
3. If there is not enough space to display var1, then DO NOT display var1 and display var2 only.

Note: both var1 and var2 are dynamic values of variable length.

Hope the image below makes my question clear.

Example
[image]

Comment: What happens if 1) there's enough space for `var1` but not enough for `var2`. 2) there is not enough space to display both…? Not clear what exactly you want to do...

Comment: set the table `width` to `width="100%"` so that it takes the entire content area to fit the size

Comment: @TJ hope the image makes it clear.